# How to disable content view in windows explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, script, active-directory, group-policy

Im trying to find a way to disable content view in windows explorer on windows 7 clients.

I found this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744697%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#WS_TurnOffDisplayofSnippets

Though this doesn't seem to do the trick. Even if i edit the local group policy manually of a machine and enable this setting, it doesn't seem to disable this view and i can manually open windows explorer and enable this view.

Any ideas?

Comment: That particular GP is for disabling content view *by default*, it does not completely disable it

Comment: Yea thats what i have noticed.  So is there no way to disable this?  Anyways in powershell?

Comment: There is not...